# Function naming in C: parentheses in function names

Tags: c, naming-conventions

I was reading a source code when I saw functions with parentheses in their names:

```
extern int LIB_(strcmp) ( const char* s1, const char* s2 );
extern char LIB_(tolower) ( char c );
```

What is that?

I am confused because I could call the functions like this: `char c = LIB_(tolower)('A');`

Isn't it true that in C, parentheses are used to separate function names from parameters and to do type casting?

Comment: The `LIB_(tolower)` interface does not match the standard C `tolower()` function interface. The standard function takes an `int` and returns an `int` — it accepts EOF as well as any valid character value (treated as an `unsigned char` promoted to `int`).  Be wary of this library! One reason for a similar notation (`int (function_name)(int arg1, char *arg2) { … }`) is that a function-like macro `#define function_name(x, y) …` defining a macro implementation of the function does not affect the function definition because the close parenthesis after the name means it is not a macro invocation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is indeed confusing. `LIB_(x)` is a *macro* defined somewhere, which evaluates to the real name of the function.

So the function's name is not actually `LIB_(strcmp)` but the result of the `LIB_(x)` macro. Most likely, `LIB_(x)` is intended to prepend a library name/identifier onto the beginning of the function and is defined like this:

```
/* prepend libname_ onto the name of the function (x) */
#define LIB_(x) libname_ ## x
```

Comment: You are correct, but now I have a follow up question: why they did that? is there a reason you want to change the name of the functions with a macro rather than giving them the right name in the first place. for example why they didn't declare the functions like `libname_strcmp`?

Comment: @Hesam Just guessing here, but maybe some of the functions are reused in other libraries; all they'd have to do is change the macro to get consistent function names? That's the only thing I can think of. Can you contact the author(s) and ask them?

Comment: I can, but I thought maybe this is a common thing in C libraries. Thank you.

Comment: @Hesam You're welcome. I think I may have seen it once, but I don't remember for sure or where. I haven't worked with C libraries as much as some others though, so my experiences may not be representative...

Answer (score 1):

You don't only see parenthesis around their names, you see more, for example `LIB_(strcmp)`. Somewhere in your source, `LIB_` is defined as a macro; to understand what's happening you need to read what that macro does.

This is generally done to either modify the names of functions in a library in some standardized naming convention, or add attributes to the function (in a compiler specific way).

Answer (score 0):

I  believe `LIB_` is a macro defined somewhere.